# Getting confused with Reference Casting and Widening w.r.t Objects in java

Tags: java

With primitives and their Wrappers I understood the concept of Widening. But with respect to other Objects I am getting confused with Widening and implicit Casting. As example

```
       Class Animal{
        }

        Class Dog extends Animal{

         public static void main(args String[]){

         Dog d = new Dog();
         d.go(d);
        }

       void go(Animal a){    }
      }
```

Edit: the question is which one is preferred widening or casting and why?

Answer (score 1):

(In my opinion) if the casting isn't required then don't do it.  Your code will be more readable.

In particular, the syntax:

```
 d.go(d);
```

is more concise, and just as correct as

```
d.go((Animal)d);
```

Basically, take advantage of the widening for reasons I describe below in my first attempt to answer your question.

---

Well, it depends on what you want the code to accomplish.

If you want a function that can deal with any kind of Animal, Dogs or otherwise, then you should take as input an Animal.

If you want a function that requires something that only Dogs have, or that only makes sense as an operation that takes Dogs as input, then you should take as input a Dog.

edit: perhaps a more contrived example will illustrate why this isn't a question with a straightforward uinversal answer.  In Java all objects are children of Object, and as such, any method can be written such that it takes a parameter `Object foo`.

Sometimes this can be useful, but its use cases are really quite restrictive, you're limited to the defined methods on `Object`.

Suppose instead that you know about `Dog`, which is also an `Object`.  Rather than passing an instance of `Dog` as an `Object` you might want to get some property *specific* to `Dog`.  Basically, if you need to ensure that the argument to some function conforms to some contract, you should restrict the argument to types that conform -- slightly differently: *if you need to know that it's a Dog declare it to be a Dog*.

As a general rule, you should (in my opinion) choose the "widest" type that conforms to whatever contract you need to fulfill. *If you need to know that it's an Animal declare it to be an Animal*.

Comment: I didnt understand what you are trying to say. I asked in above example which one is prefererd.

Comment: @gurukulki, any "preference" depends on what your code needs to accomplish (there is no universal answer here). I gave examples of when widening is preferred, and when being narrow is preferred.

Comment: but i asked when widening is prefrerred and casting is preferred

Comment: @gurukulki, indeed, it seems like my first pass completely missed the mark, edited appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mark in saying that it depends. I use a rule of thumb which basically just says that casts of declared types to a subtype are "bad". So if somewhere in your method

`void go(Animal a){ ... }`

you need a cast like

`Dog d = (Dog) a;`

you should definitely (if possible) change the parameter a of type Animal to a parameter of type Dog. If the method works on all subtypes of `Animal` without a cast then leave it as it is.